# The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, runtime-error, projects-and-solutions

I am working on a Visual studio project
Project A (which generates a static lib on compilation)

has a class

```
using namespace mynamespace;
class projectAclass
{
  virtual int  funct1()=0;  //Pure virtual function
  virtual int funct2()=0;  //Pure virtual function
  virtual int funct3()=0;  //Pure virtual function
};
```

Project B(which generates a DLL on compilation)

```
#define projectBclass_DLL __declspec( dllexport )
class projectBclass_DLL projectBclass: public mynamespace::projectAclass
{
  //Definitions of the 3 pure virtual functions are here
  int funct1() 
  {
    //definition go here
  }
  //similarly for funct2 and funct3

  int funct4()
 { //Definition goes here    }
  int funct5()
 { //Definition goes here    }
  int funct6()
 { //Definition goes here    }
};
```

Now from the main function created in some other project I have created an object of class **projectAclass** and trying to call function **funct1** but i don't know some other function is getting called that are defined in **projectBclass** (let say funct4) when i am trying to debug the solution and after returning from **funct4** I am getting this error

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a
function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with
one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling
convention.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I presume you haven't actually "created an object of class projectAclass " because it is abstract.

Comment: The debugger warning is just a side effect of the wrong function getting called.  It is entirely unclear why this happens but of course you can never call funct4() on a projectAclass object, it doesn't have this function and is abstract so can never be created, so the info in this question cannot be accurate.

Comment: @HansPassant Sir can you tell me how to fix this exception(ESP was not properly....)

Comment: Does the declspec export the base class too?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you have the [calling conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142644/weird-msc-8-0-error-the-value-of-esp-was-not-properly-saved-across-a-function) wrong. Sometimes a rebuild of everything will sort it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the static library that is linked to your dll, the dll and (because you are creating a C++ DLL) your application have the same build configuration (DEBUG/RELEASE).
Check the preprocessor flags in your project. Wrong preprocessor flags can lead to different virtual function pointer tables and therefore it can easily happen that the wrong function is called.

Comment: I have checked all have the same build configuration but still it is giving that exception